# Finding elements of a vector based on the numerical positions defined in another vector in R

Tags: r, loops, subset, lapply, sapply

Suppose I have the following two vectors. `ll` defines the number and borderlines among ***sets*** of the elements in `long`.

For example, here based on `ll`, the first two elements in `long` are a separate set, then the one element after those is a separate set, and so on.

I was wondering how I could automatically (perhaps as a `sapply`) subset each set from `long` based on `ll`?

```
ll <- c(2, 1, 2, 3)
long <- c(F, F, F, F, T, T, F, T)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `split` to split by `rep(seq_along(ll), ll)` (outputs `1 1 2 3 3 4 4 4`).

```
split(long, rep(seq_along(ll), ll))

$`1`
[1] FALSE FALSE

$`2`
[1] FALSE

$`3`
[1] FALSE  TRUE

$`4`
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```